# In perl, is $self->subname the same as $self->MYPACKAGE::subname?

Tags: perl

In perl, is `$self->subname` the same as `$self->MYPACKAGE::subname`?  It's me the author of [Pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer) with yet another piece of mystery Perl code, this one is again from CGI.pm.  Here the code is taking `$self`, which is an instance variable of the CGI package, and then calling the `hidden` function, defined within, but the code doesn't just use `$self->hidden(...)`, it uses `$self->CGI::hidden(...)`.  When I translate this to Python as `self.CGI.hidden(...)`, I get an error that the CGI class doesn't have a CGI attribute.  I'm wondering if I should make a CGI attribute in this case that just points back to the class instance (or should it point to the class)?  Anyhow, what exactly does this mean?

```
package CGI;
...
sub hidden { ... }
...
$self->CGI::hidden(...);
```

Comment: As I noted on a previous question for you, don't translate Perl to Python. Understand what an interface point is doing, and reimplement that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74678226/in-perl-is-stdin-the-same-as-stdin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In perl, is $self->subname the same as $self->MYPACKAGE::subname

No.

`$self->subname` will look up `subname` in the symbol table associated with object `$self`, which is the symbol table from the package were `$self` is blessed into.

`$self->MYPACKAGE::subname` instead is mostly (but not exactly - see comment below from tobyink) like calling `MYPACKAGE::subname($self)`, i.e. it will not lookup the method in the symbol table associated with `$self` but instead in the symbol table for `MYPACKAGE` (and its parent packages). `$self` might not even have a method `subname`.

Comment: Nit: Neither `$self` nor its value is the object, and  neither `$self` nor its value is blessed. It's the referenced hash (or whatever) that's blessed.

Comment: `$self->MYPACKAGE::subname` and `MYPACKAGE::subname($self)` are actually a little different. The former will respect inheritance, and search MYPACKAGE's parents if MYPACKAGE doesn't have a sub of that name.